# Full-screen images are being cut off

Tags: css, image

I am trying to load images full-screen for a photography site.

The images successfully load full-screen, but they are overflowing the area of the browser, thus cutting off parts of the photos.

I am using a template called Brushed (http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/), and believe I have identified the relevant css to this area:

```
#supersized {
display:block; 
position:fixed; 
left:0; top:0;
overflow:visible; 
z-index:-1; height:100%; 
width:100%; 
margin:0; 
padding:0;}
```

Wondering if anyone in the stackoverflow community can see anything in this bit of css that would be causing that, or can provide a workaround suggestion.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When working with full screen images, there will always be parts of the image cut off due to many screen resolutions / sizes. This is done to maintain the ratio of the image.

The 'causing' of the missing parts is not your above CSS code example but is the inline generated CSS styling done by the [jQuery supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) plugin.

```
<img src="_include/img/slider-images/image01.jpg" style="width: 1903px; left: 0px; top: -415.5px; height: 1275.01px;">
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for that answer. That definitely makes sense. Really appreciate it.